# Pass data from collectionCell inside tableCell to secondVC use protocol

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, collections, protocols

I have two viewController's. The first VC has `collectionCell` inside `tableCell`. The second VC has `collectionCell`, and I have swift `File` with Model have a class. I need to pass data from the first VC (`collectionCell`) to the second VC.

Pass data need from `collectionCell` because `collectionCell` has images (from swift File - Model). I think need use a protocol, but I don't really understand how to work with a protocol. Please help.

My code:

**1stVC**(**viewController**):

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var image: [Model] = []
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Студии2")

        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            var newImages: [Model] = []

            for item in snapshot.children {
                let object = Model(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                newImages.append(object)
            }
            self.image = newImages
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
extension ViewController1: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return image.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell1
        cell.images = [image[indexPath.row].image,
                       image[indexPath.row].image2]
        return cell
    }
}
```

**1stVC**(**collectionCell inside tableCell**):

```
protocol PostDelegate {
    func selectedPost(cell: String)
}

class TableViewCell1: UITableViewCell {

    var images = [String]()
    var selecetdItem: Model?
    var postDelegate: PostDelegate?

}
extension TableViewCell1: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return images.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell1

        cell.imagesView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: images[indexPath.item]))

        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        postDelegate?.selectedPost(cell: self.images[indexPath.item])
        print(images[indexPath.item])
    }
}
```

**2ndVC**(**viewController**):

```
class ViewController3: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

//    var images = [String]()
    var images: [Model] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
extension ViewController3: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell3
//        let array = [images[indexPath.item].images,
//                     images[indexPath.item].images2]
//        cell.imagesView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: array[indexPath.item]))
//        cell.imagesView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: images[indexPath.item]))
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Model**(**swift File have a class**):

```
class Model {
    var image: String!
    var image2: String!
    var images: [String] = []
    var images2: [String] = []
    var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!

    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        ref = snapshot.ref
        let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
        let snap1 = value["hall1"] as? NSDictionary
        let snap2 = value["hall2"] as? NSDictionary
        image = snap1?["qwerty"] as? String ?? ""
        image2 = snap2?["qwerty"] as? String ?? ""
        if let post1 = snap1 as? [String: AnyObject] {
            for (_, value) in post1["images"] as! [String: AnyObject] {
                self.images.append(value as! String)
            }
        }
        if let post1 = snap1 as? [String: AnyObject] {
            for (_, value) in post1["images"] as! [String: AnyObject] {
                self.images2.append(value as! String)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass ViewController1 as the postDelegate of `TableViewCell1`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell1
      //make VC1 as post delegate of cell
      (cell as! TableViewCell1).postDelegate = self
      cell.images = [image[indexPath.row].image,
                           image[indexPath.row].image2]
      return cell
}
```

Finally implement

```
extension ViewController1 : PostDelegate {
    func selectedPost(cell: String) {
         //call self.perform segue or load VC2 and pass data here
    }
}
```

**Pinch of Advice :**

```
var postDelegate: PostDelegate?
```

will result in strongly holding a reference to the delegate being passed. Which will result in memory leaks. To make it safer declare delegate as `weak`

```
weak var postDelegate: PostDelegate?
```

In order to make the Protocol weak your protocol

```
protocol PostDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func selectedPost(cell: String)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i little don't understand. What do you mean in this comment: **//call self.perform segue or load VC2 and pass data here**? What me need to write here?

Comment: its up to you how would you like to load ViewController3 once user taps on CollectionView Cell. For example If you are using storyboard you might simply drag a segue from ViewConytroller1 to ViewController3 and provide reusable identifier to it and later call self.performSegue(with identifier) and use Segue delegate prepare for segue to get the reference of ViewController3 being loaded and pass the data to it Second way, create a instance of ViewCOntroller3.init(with nib name: bundle :) and then pass data to it and finally call self.pushViewController or self.presentViewController

Comment: @onpro : Please consider accepting answer if it helped

Comment: i will check today