# Get table row index on click of its table cell's collection item?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a tableview which has multiple rows , in each row I have collection view with multiple items that scrolls horizontally . Now I want to get the exact tableview row index whose collection cell's item i have clicked.My tableview delegate methods are in `ViewController.m` file and collection cell delegate methods are in `TableCell.m` file. And on click collection view item only collection view `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is called in which i am not able to get the tablview row index. Please help me with some suggestions how to get the table row index.

Comment: write a delegate between tableViewCell and ViewController pass viewController as delegate to tableViewCell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, trigger the delegate in TableViewCell's didSelectItemAtIndexPath implementation, pass the self (cell in this case) as parameter in delegate method so your viewController gets the tabView cell when collectionView inside it is tapped now get the indexPath for the cell using indexPathForCell thats all. I have answered a similar question in past lemme see if I can find it and post the link here for further help

Comment: Something similar (though not exact same) to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152360/pass-data-from-collectioncell-inside-tablecell-to-secondvc-use-protocol/46152465#46152465

Comment: Okay .. i will try this

Comment: @SandeepBhandari...Thank you so much it worked

Comment: You are always welcome buddy :) Now you can either add it as answer and accept it yourself or if you think its duplicate you can delete the question :) Happy coding :) cheers